# Problems with this stack implementation

Tags: c, stack, c-strings

where is the mistake?

My code here:

```
 typedef struct _box
    {
        char *dados;
        struct _box * proximo;
    } Box;

    typedef struct _pilha
    {
        Box * topo;
    }Stack;

void Push(Stack *p, char * algo)
{
    Box *caixa;
    if (!p)
    {
        exit(1);
    }

    caixa = (Box *) calloc(1, sizeof(Box));
    caixa->dados = algo;
    caixa->proximo = p->topo;
    p->topo = caixa;
}


char * Pop(Stack *p)
{
    Box *novo_topo;
    char * dados;
    if (!p)
    {
        exit(1);
    }

    if (p->topo==NULL)
        return NULL;

    novo_topo = p->topo->proximo;

    dados = p->topo->dados;

    free(p->topo);
    p->topo = novo_topo;

    return dados;
}


void StackDestroy(Stack *p)
{
    char * c;
    if (!p)
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    c = NULL;
    while ((c = Pop(p)) != NULL)
    {
        free(c);
    }
    free(p);
}

int main()
{
int conjunto = 1;
char p[30], * v;
int flag = 0;

Stack *pilha = (Stack *) calloc(1, sizeof(Stack));

FILE* arquivoIN = fopen("L1Q3.in","r");
FILE* arquivoOUT = fopen("L1Q3.out","w");

if (arquivoIN == NULL)
{
    printf("Erro na leitura do arquivo!\n\n");
    exit(1);
}

fprintf(arquivoOUT,"Conjunto #%d\n",conjunto);

while (fscanf(arquivoIN,"%s", p) != EOF )
{
    if (pilha->topo == NULL && flag != 0)
    {
        conjunto++;
        fprintf(arquivoOUT,"\nConjunto #%d\n",conjunto);
    }

    if(strcmp(p, "return") != 0)
    {
        Push(pilha, p);
    }

    else
    {
        v = Pop(pilha);

        if(v != NULL)
        {
            fprintf(arquivoOUT, "%s\n", v);
        }
    }
    flag = 1;
}

StackDestroy(pilha);

return 0;
```

}

The Pop function returns the string value read from file.
But is not correct and i don't know why.

Comment: Although someone might be able to spot a problem, you have a higher chance of getting an answer if you include some details like what exactly is "not correct" about your program, what failure you are seeing, what you have tried to fix it, and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not allocating any storage for the strings pointed to by `dados` - you're just re-using one string buffer (`p`) and passing that around, so all your stack elements just point to this one string.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  The `Box` objects that you're storing in the stack contain `char *` pointers -- they don't actually contain the strings themselves.  So, you create a `Box` pushed onto the stack, and it points to where `p` is, and then you change `p` in reading the next value, and since the `Box` already on the stack is still pointing to `p`, it's now pointing at the changed value.

Comment: Oh my god!
thank you very much!
=D

I have had spent many time with this problem, must be the lack of caffeine =)